# html2canvas resetting letter spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

```js
$('#cypher-branding-letter-spacing').change(function(e) {
  $('#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text').css('letter-spacing', $('#cypher-branding-letter-spacing').val() + 'px');
});

//add text to design
$(document).on('click', '#cypher-branding-btn-add-to-design-text', function() {

  //remove the canvas border before creating the image, then add it back
  $("#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text-wrapper").css('border', 'none');

  html2canvas($("#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text-wrapper"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var id = guid();

      var img = new Image();
      img = $('#cypher-branding-text-temp-img').find('img')[0];
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;

      //var elem = $('<div id="cypher_container_' + id + '" class="cypher-container"><div id="cypher_container_inner_' + id + '" class="tooltip"><img id="cypher_container_img' + id + '" onclick=showLogoCommands("' + id + '"); src="' + img.src + '" class="cypher-blocks" style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px" /><span class="tooltiptext"><a href="#" onclick=rotatePlus("' + id + '");>Rotate +</a><a href="#" onclick=rotateMinus("' + id + '");>Rotate -</a><a href="#" onclick=removeFromDesign("' + id + '");>Remove</a><br /></span></div></div>');
      var elem = $('<div id="cypher_container_' + id + '" class="cypher-container" style="width:100px;"><div id="cypher_container_inner_' + id + '" class="tooltip"><span class="tooltiptext"><a href="#" onclick=removeFromDesign("' + id + '");>x</a><br /></span><img id="cypher_container_img' + id + '" onclick=showLogoCommands("' + id + '"); src="' + img.src + '" class="cypher-blocks" style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px" /></div></div>');
      $('.cypher-block').append(elem);

      elem.draggable({
        cancel: ".ui-rotatable-handle"
      });

      //rotate handles
      var nw = $("<div>", {
        class: "ui-rotatable-handle"
      });
      var ne = nw.clone();
      var se = nw.clone();

      elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').resizable();
      elem.rotatable();

      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-sw");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-nw");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-ne");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-se");
      // Assign handles to box
      elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').append(nw, ne, se);

      elem.find("div[class*='ui-rotatable-handle-']").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
        elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').rotatable("instance").startRotate(e);
      });
    }
  });

  //$("#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text-wrapper").css('border', '1px dashed #777');

});
```

```css
.cypher-blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: initial;
  cursor: move;
}

.cypher-block {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cypher-block .ui-resizable-handle,
.cypher-block .ui-resizable-se {
  border: none;
  background-color: none;
  color: none;
  background-image: url("")
}

.cypher-block .ui-resizable-handle {}

.cypher-block .ui-rotatable-handle {
  background-image: url("")
}

.cypher-block:hover .ui-resizable-handle,
.cypher-block:hover .ui-resizable-se {
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  resize: both;
}

.cypher-block:hover .ui-rotatable-handle {
  background: url('cypher-brand/rotate.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="cypher-block" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>


<div id="cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text-wrapper" style="width:300px;height:170px;padding:0;">
  <div id="cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text">Sample Text</div>
</div>


<input type="number" id="cypher-branding-letter-spacing" class="cypher-branding-text-input" value="0" />

<span id="cypher-branding-btn-add-to-design-text" class="cypher-branding-input-btn cypher-branding-command-padding">Add to Product Design</span>
```

I'm trying to create an image from text, then add it to another div.

The issue is with 'letter-spacing' CSS style.

After applying the CSS, then creating an image using html2canvas, the CSS on the image  does not show.

Just to note, all other CSS styles I apply to the div shows, like line-spacing, color, font etc. It's only letter-spacing that is the issue.

I've added a snippet, however it's giving me a 'Script error' this is only when adding the external scripts. Not sure yet on how to resolve it as I'm new to snippets.

Comment: Did you customize the css for `.line-spacing` or is that included in something else? If you did create your own css, please include it. Also, it might be good to use the snippet option here.

Comment: @adpro I'm not sure where you are seeing .line-spacing? My question is regarding letter-spacing. All CSS applied via JavaScript is done so on the .css('','') method.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong text from your question.  I meant to put `letter-spacing`.  Are all of the styles applied in JS as well? I see you're adding CSS classes to elements, but you didn't include the styles.  Have you changed the styles? When you say the CSS does not show, do you mean it isn't being applied to the selector, or are the styles not showing? Where are you setting the styles? In a CSS file? I think more information is needed to troubleshoot further. My copy mistake doesn't take away from the rest of my comment.

Comment: I also don't see `#cypher-branding-letter-spacing` in your markup. Is the JS getting into that change event handler function? Have you stepped through to make sure it's getting in there and applying your css classes? If so, the styles would need to be included. That's where I would start. And get a working snippet for us.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind - needed to do full screen.

Comment: @ad It's ok. Yes all styles are applied in JS. I've now included part of the stylesheet for the .cypher-block and .cypher-blocks styles. The CSS is applied to the initial div, before html2canvas is called. After the div is converted to a png, the style does not carry over to the image. All styles are set in JS. This is for the customer to choose their own formating for the text via a UI of styles. All other styles work well. Like I can apply font, line-spacing, font-size, color etc, and they all apply and are saved to the png. Only letter-spacing is ignored.

Comment: @adpro for some reason after adding the external JS file to the snippet, it gives the 'Script error'  message/ Not sure how to resolve this?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. It seems the style you're having an issue with is an element style, not coming in from a class. I'm wondering if it ignores the element styles when you generate that png.

Comment: @adpro it only ignores the letter-spacing style when generating the png. All other styles are applied and generated fine. I'm puzzled right now with the letter-spacing :/

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `letterRendering:true`

```
  html2canvas($("#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text-wrapper"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var id = guid();

      var img = new Image();
      img = $('#cypher-branding-text-temp-img').find('img')[0];
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;

      //var elem = $('<div id="cypher_container_' + id + '" class="cypher-container"><div id="cypher_container_inner_' + id + '" class="tooltip"><img id="cypher_container_img' + id + '" onclick=showLogoCommands("' + id + '"); src="' + img.src + '" class="cypher-blocks" style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px" /><span class="tooltiptext"><a href="#" onclick=rotatePlus("' + id + '");>Rotate +</a><a href="#" onclick=rotateMinus("' + id + '");>Rotate -</a><a href="#" onclick=removeFromDesign("' + id + '");>Remove</a><br /></span></div></div>');
      var elem = $('<div id="cypher_container_' + id + '" class="cypher-container" style="width:100px;"><div id="cypher_container_inner_' + id + '" class="tooltip"><span class="tooltiptext"><a href="#" onclick=removeFromDesign("' + id + '");>x</a><br /></span><img id="cypher_container_img' + id + '" onclick=showLogoCommands("' + id + '"); src="' + img.src + '" class="cypher-blocks" style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px" /></div></div>');
      $('.cypher-block').append(elem);

      elem.draggable({
        cancel: ".ui-rotatable-handle"
      });

      //rotate handles
      var nw = $("<div>", {
        class: "ui-rotatable-handle"
      });
      var ne = nw.clone();
      var se = nw.clone();

      elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').resizable();
      elem.rotatable();

      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-sw");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-nw");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-ne");
      elem.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-se");
      // Assign handles to box
      elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').append(nw, ne, se);

      elem.find("div[class*='ui-rotatable-handle-']").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
        elem.find('.cypher-blocks:first').rotatable("instance").startRotate(e);
      });
    },
    letterRendering:true
  });
```

That should work I think.

Based on this [Letter-spacing isn't supported](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/559)